# How to detect key press without using an input tag in Blazor

Tags: input, keyboard, blazor

I want to be able to capture keyboard input without using an HTML INPUT tag in Blazor. Once the key is pressed i will display a graphic to represent the letter pressed.

Something like this

```
@page "/counter"
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Web

<div @onkeypress="e => KeyPress(e)">
    Press any letter key
</div>

@code {

    private void KeyPress(KeyboardEventArgs e)
    {
        var letter = e.Key;
    }
}
```

The KeyPress method does not appear to be called when I set a breakpoint on it. Any help much appreciated.

Comment: The div will need to contain focus to intercept keys.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You are almost there, but you forgot to make div focused. This is the steps:

0.- Make your div focusable adding `tabindex` tag:

```html
<div 
    class="jumbotron"
    @onkeydown="@KeyDown"
    tabindex="0"
    @ref="myDiv" >
   <h1 class="display-4">
       @letter
   </h1>   
</div>
```

1.- Create a js code to set focus to your div, on `_Host.cshtml` for example:

```js
    <script>
        window.SetFocusToElement = (element) => {
            element.focus();
        };
    </script>
```

This function takes an Element reference as the parameter.

2.- Call this function after your component is rendered.

```cs
protected ElementReference myDiv;  // set by the @ref attribute

protected async override Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
{
    if (firstRender) 
    {
        await JSRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("SetFocusToElement", myDiv);
    }            
}
```

3.- Implement your own `KeyDown`:

```cs
protected void KeyDown(KeyboardEventArgs e)
{
    letter = $"Pressed: [{e.Key}]";
}
```

*Notice that this is not a Blazor issue, is just the default html and js behavior. I learned it writing a game, check it out at [Blagario](https://github.com/ctrl-alt-d/Blagario) lab.*

**Running:**

[image: Flappy Blazor Bird]

*Demo at [Flappy Blazor Bird](https://github.com/ctrl-alt-d/FlappyBlazorBird)*

**Edited Nov 2019:**

*Code improved by [@Quango](https://stackoverflow.com/users/41403/quango) (many thanks)*

Comment: Suggestion: change the js code so it's generic:
```
<script>
        window.SetFocusTo = (id) => {
            document.getElementById(id).focus();
        };
    </script>
```

Comment: Actually @dani a better approach still is to use Blazor's `@ref` feature and pass the element, then the code is just `[element].focus()` - this avoids the need to assign IDs

Comment: @daniherrera no problem. I also amended the call to be `InvokeVoidAsync` since there is no return value. The `ElementReference` approach is recommended since it avoids the need to use `id`s - for example if using a component more than once

Answer (score 26):

If there is still someone who want the solution. I think now in .NET 5 you can achieve this in Blazor without js. To set focus and tabindex is important, when you lost focus, or set focus to another element this will not work. This works for me:

```cs
    <table @ref="testRef" tabindex="0" @onkeydown="HandleKeyDown">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>
                Pressed Key
            </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>
                @pressedKey
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
    </table>

    private ElementReference testRef;
    private string pressedKey;
    
    private void HandleKeyDown(KeyboardEventArgs e)
    {
        pressedKey = e.Key;
    }

    protected override async Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
    {
        if (firstRender)
        {
            await testRef.FocusAsync();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an easier way to do it (without JS).
First create a div like this:

```
<div @ref="keyDownDiv" @onkeydown="KeyPress"></div>
```

Add a Variable for your reference to your code:

```
private ElementReference keyDownDiv;
```

Now you can use this line:

```
await keyDownDiv.FocusAsync();
```

The Focus of the Browser will be set on your div and it will trigger the OnKeyDown event.
Tip: if the user presses any other button, the focus will change and it wont work anymore! In this case just use FocusAsync again.