# How do I set focus to a text box in Blazor

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side

How do I set focus to a textbox in Blazor? So far the only way we have found is with JavaScript.

Comment: Here it is: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58920875/842935

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to set the focus to an InputText element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59137973/how-to-set-the-focus-to-an-inputtext-element)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no other way to do it... You can use JSInterop to do this, as follows:

```
 <input type="text" @ref="myref"/>

 @code {

    private ElementReference myref;
    [Inject] IJSRuntime JSRuntime { get; set; }

     protected override async Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
    {
         if (firstRender)
        {
            await 
        JSRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("exampleJsFunctions.focusElement", myref);
        }
   }
 }
```

### JavaScript

```
<script>

    window.exampleJsFunctions =
    {
        focusElement: function (element) {
           element.focus();
        }
    };
</script>
```

Hope this helps...

Comment: see below answer

Answer (score 40):

.Net 5 (or higher) makes this easy!

```
<input type="text" @ref="myref"/>

@code {

    private ElementReference myref;

    protected override async Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
    {
        if (firstRender)
        {
            await myref.FocusAsync();
        }
   }
}
```

Comment: Many examples for FocusAsync fail to mention that it must be called in the OnAfterRenderAsync method (as Alexandre shows). Also don't miss that FocusAsync has an optional bool arg that scrolls the focused element into view.

Comment: Works great! I'm posting an answer for Radzen components below (it's slightly different, but needs to be shared here).

Answer (score 6):

If you have a built-in type like `InputNumber` and you are using `.Net6`, you can apply the solution of @Alexandre but with some changes like this:

```
<InputNumber @ref="MyRef" @bind-Value="MyValue" />
<button class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="MyClick"> Click me </button>

private InputNumber<int> MyRef;
private int MyValue {get; set;}

//Some click event
private void MyClick()
{
   if(MyRef.Element.HasValue) 
   {
     MyRef.Element.Value.FocusAsync();
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

For those of us using a 3rd party control, the provider should have an equivalent element reference to make Alexandre's answer work (DotNet5 and up)

```
<RadzenTextBox @ref="searchBox" Name="SearchPhrase" @bind-Value=@SearchString MaxLength="400" @oninput=@(args => OnChangedSearch(args.Value.ToString())) @onkeydown="@Enter" />
        
     @code{   
            RadzenTextBox searchBox;
            protected override async Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
            {
                if (firstRender)
                {
                    await searchBox.Element.FocusAsync(); //NOTE: this is for Radzen "elements"
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

This Demo Shows that by clicking on button focus set to textbox.

```
@page "/setfocus"

<input @ref="textInput" />

<button @onclick="() => 
textInput.FocusAsync()">Set
    focus</button>

@code {
    ElementReference textInput;
}
```

Comment: As several other questions/answers have pointed out, this does not always work. You need to defer the `FocusAsync` call until `OnAfterRenderAsync` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72411471/blazors-focusasync-doesnt-always-set-focus

Answer (score 0):

In .NET 7 Maui Blazor, this worked when I tested.

1. Put the following Js method in index.html inside script tag 'text/javascript'

   ```
    window.exampleJsFunctions =
    {
        focusElement: function (elementId) {
            var el = document.getElementById(elementId);
            if (!!el) {
                el.focus();
            }
        }
    };
   ```
2. Add the following method to a .razor file, say the element urlTextRef should be focused

   ```
   private InputText urlTextRef;

    protected override async Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
    {
            if (firstRender)
            {
                await JS.InvokeVoidAsync("exampleJsFunctions.focusElement", urlTextRef?.Element?.Id);
            }
    }
   ```

This override uses a InputText and sets an id.

```
   <InputText @ref="urlTextRef" id="articleUrl" @bind-Value="Model!.ArticleUrl" placeholder="Skriv inn url til artikkel i Dagbladet" />
```