# Issue with Modal in Bootstrap 5 - Blazor

Tags: javascript, html, server, blazor, bootstrap-5

I'm working on a Blazor application using Bootstrap for modal handling. I'm trying to use the data-bs-backdrop and data-bs-keyboard attributes in my ModalAlert.razor component to control the behavior of the backdrop and keyboard when the modal is open.

The problem I'm facing is that the backdrop is displayed correctly when the modal is open, but it doesn't prevent closing the modal by clicking on it, even though I've set data-bs-backdrop="static" and data-bs-keyboard="false".

What am I doing wrong? Can someone help me understand how to make the data-bs-backdrop attribute work correctly to prevent closing the modal by clicking on the background?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Screen of "ModalAlert.razor":
[ModalAlert.razor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j2ZJY.png)

Blazor project: Blazor Server .NET 7

Comment: Welcome to SO. [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Hi.  Put your code in a code block in your question

Comment: To use BS modals in Blazor you need to do a little work.  Some of the JS stuff doesn't play well with the Blazor virtual DOM.  Search "Blazor Modal Dialog" on Bing for plenty of implementations you can use.  You don't need to reinvent the wheel early in your Blazor journey.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: This may give you clues on how to manage this in Blazor https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70156540/it-possible-to-click-outside-an-element-to-close-it-on-blazor

Answer (score 0):

if you add bootsrap.bundle.min.js and bootstrap.min.cs files to _Host.cshtml,
it should work correctly.
by the way, do you have any console error? check this (browser inspect tools F-12). if yes please inform us more.

How do you open Modal?
How do you Close Modal?
Do you use IJSRuntime and bootstrap Modal JS functions?

I would update this post after you inform us more.

Comment: I've added both files correctly, and i've no errors in console

Comment: I open my modal in this way: 
        _module?.InvokeVoidAsync("show", _modalInstance).ConfigureAwait(false).GetAwaiter();