# Blazor's FocusAsync doesn't always set focus

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side

I can't make .NET 6's Blazor AsyncFocus  method work.

Near as I can tell, AsyncFocus only works when a component value isn't null. The model ensures the component value isn't null.

Model:

```cs
namespace BlazorAppWithService.Models;

public class TagModel
{
    public string? TagName { get; set; } = "";
}
```

Blazor markup:

```html
<EditForm Model="@newTag" OnValidSubmit="AddTag">
    <InputText @ref="ele "@bind-Value="newTag.TagName"></InputText>
    <button type="submit">Add tag</button>
</EditForm>
```

This code:

```cs
@code {
    InputText ele;

    private List<TagModel> tagList = new List<TagModel>();

    private TagModel newTag = new TagModel();


    protected override async Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
    {
        if (firstRender) 
            if (ele.Element != null)
                await ele.Element.Value.FocusAsync();
    }

    private async void AddTag()
    {
        tagList.Add(newTag);
        newTag = new TagModel();
        if (ele.Element != null)
        {
            await ele.Element.Value.FocusAsync();            
        }
    }
}
```

This code correctly sets focus on the first render, but the component is not focused when the AddTag() method is called.

FWIW, this doesn't position cursor either:

```html
<button @onclick="() => ele.Element.Value.FocusAsync()" type="submit">Add tag</button>
```

Blazor: Making the hard things easy and the easy things hard!

Comment: The ele variable mustn't be a ElementReference type? And then do ele.FocusAsync() ?

Answer (score 7):

To explain what is going on `FocusAsync` under the hood is calling JavaScript, but Blazor is rerendering after this happens. Therefore, you need to call `FocusAsync`in the OnAfterRenderAsync method like so:

```
protected override async Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
{
    await ele.Element.Value.FocusAsync();
}
```

Probably it isn't very apparent that `FocusAsync` uses JavaScript, but this is the reason why it doesn't work. There is this excerpt from the documentation about calling JavaScript:

> **To delay JavaScript interop calls until a point where such calls are guaranteed to work**, override the OnAfterRender{Async} lifecycle
> event. This event is only called after the app is fully rendered.

[source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/javascript-interoperability/call-javascript-from-dotnet?view=aspnetcore-6.0)

Comment: That makes perfect sense. Thank you, Jesse.

Comment: Calling it on `OnAfterRenderAsync` but still no focus.

Answer (score 0):

For me, the problem was the target element not being there. Imagine this scenario:

```cs
if (ShowInput)
{
    <input @ref="MyInput" />
}

@code{
    bool ShowInput { get; set; }
    ElementReference? MyInput { get; set; }
    async Task SomeOperation()
    {
        ShowInput = true;
        //Here, Blazor should render the input, but has not yet. Currently there is no input.
        await MyInput.FocusAsync();
    }
}
```

So we should always somehow call `FocusAsync` after rendering the element completely. Beware that container components like `EditForm` can affect the rendering behavior of their children. (Which I believe is the source of your problem.)